# The possibility and meaning of $u(x) <_B \parallel x \in u \parallel^B$ when forcing with $B$

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra, forcing

I was trying to understand better boolean valued models for forcing and I have the following question : Why is the this formula an inequality and not an equality ?

$$(u(x)\leq\parallel x \in u \parallel^B )$$

For instance if i have the name $$p_0= <\emptyset, 0>$$ and $$u=<{p_0,0}>$$

then i would get $$u(p_0) =0 $$ and $$ \parallel p_0 \in u \parallel^B=0$$ right ? could u give me an example where $$u(x)< \parallel u \in x \parallel^B $$?? Furthermore which property of first order logic does this inequality reflect ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks !. Hope the question is clearer now!

Comment: @JesusMartinez You mean $(u(x)\leq\parallel x \in u \parallel^B )$ and $ u = \{ \langle p_0, 0 \rangle \}$, right?

Comment: Yes ! will correct it right now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is in fact possible that
$$
u(x) <_B \parallel x \in u \parallel_B.
$$

Consider for example a $B$-name $u$ with $\mathrm{dom}(u) = \{x,y\}$ such that 
$$\parallel x = y \parallel_B \wedge u(x) = 0 \text{ and } \parallel x = y \parallel_B \vee u(x) = 1$$
and $u(y) = 1$.
Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\parallel x \in u \parallel_B & = ( \parallel x = x \parallel_B \wedge u(x)) \vee ( \parallel x = y \parallel_B \wedge u(y)) \\
&= u(x) \vee \parallel x = y \parallel_B \\
&= 1
\end{align*} 
$$
but $u(x) <_B 1$.

> Furthermore which property of first order logic does this inequality reflect ?

Roughly speaking: If $g$ is a generic filter such that $u(x) \in g$ then, in $V[g]$, we have that $x^g \in u^g$. However, it is possible to have a generic filter $h$ such that $u(x) \not \in h$, yet we still have $x^h \in u^h$.

Comment: Thank you Stefan!! Your explanation is wonderfull!

Comment: @JesusMartinez You are very welcome!

Comment: Hey a quick question . So basically i am looking for a name u = {<x,1>,<y,0>} such that x and y have the same elements but at the same time they have a different truth value ? Wouldnt this conflict with the condition that u has to be a function ?  Could you maybe give me a concrete example ?

Comment: @JesusMartinez Consider $x = \{ \emptyset \} \to \{1 \}$ and $y = \{ \emptyset \} \to \{ \neg  u(x) \}$ and $u = \{ \langle x, u(x) \rangle, \langle y, 1 \rangle \}$ with $u(x) \neq 1$. This fulfills the requirement of my post. (Note that this sort of behavior cannot possibly occur for $v = \{ \langle x,1 \rangle, \langle y, 0 \rangle \}$ -- you need non-absolute (non $0/1$) forcing conditions for this kind of fuzziness to happen.)